# Django: Displaying appointment linked to a particular user on their profile only

Tags: python, django

I have a model in Django called 'Booking' to book appointments, where there are two user fields: an expert, and a user which both have ForeignKey relationships. I also have a CustomUser model and each user has a profile page. How can I specify that I want to view only the appointments linked to that particular user (or expert) on their profile page?

models.py:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null=True, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expert = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null=True, default='',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bookings')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Video call with ..', null=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField('Start time')
    end_time = models.DateTimeField('End time')
    notes = models.TextField('Notes', help_text='Please provide some detail on what you would like to learn or discuss', blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
class BookingView(CreateView):
    model = Booking
    form_class = BookingForm

def view_profile(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user
    args = {'user': user}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', args)
```

The profile displays all of the user objects fine, but I'm not sure how to call the user-linked booking objects only on the profile page. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do that in template by:

```
{% for normal_booking in user.booking_set.all %}
    {{ normal_booking.title }}
{% endfor %}

{% for expert_booking in user.bookings.all %}
    {{ expert_booking.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

And you don't need to change anything in your view. Please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) for more details.

Comment: Sorry I did not get that. But experts should be available `user.bookings.all`. If you have any entry in Booking Model which has expert FKed to `CustomUser,` then it should show the entries. BTW, CustomUser is your User Model, right? I mean it is in settings.py like `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.CustomUser'`?

Comment: Yes Im using a CustomUser model. Thanks so much for your help! I solved the problem. :)

Comment: I just wanted to clarify where you define the expert_booking. Is that automatically detected by django from the definition in the model?

Answer (score 0):

```
user_bookings = Booking.objects.filter(user=request.user) 
expert_bookings = Booking.objects.filter(expert=request.user)
```

Pass those variables to render. You can also combine the filters, but that's up to you!

Comment: Thanks! I will try this method as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProfileView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         return super().get_context_data(
              bookings=self.request.user.booking_set.all(),
              **kwargs
         )
```

Then in `profile.html` you can loop over the `bookings`